# How to Identify faulty bus pins on LCD?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, lcd

I've soldered 14 pins on the back of my LCD and connected to an AVR Microcontroller. The LCD powers on correctly and contrast is set correctly but I'm having trouble sending software initialization to the LCD via AVR Studio.The 8 bit bus pins are correctly configured to the ATMega 32 and same for the RS,RW, and En pins. I believe the error might be improper soldering.

Q: Is there a way to identify which pin, of the remaining 11, might be shorted out?

Since the pins are close I made sure that the solder does not touch adjacent pins but it's still hard to diagnose.

The LCD was receiving initialization code for a brief period but after moving the LCD around it simply stopped receiving init code all together.

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect shorted or broken wires, you may use test patterns. For AVR, most usable is to first set all pins to pullup (but not drive) and then drive low every pin one by one (0HHHHHHH -> H0HHHHHH -> HH0HHHHH...). When drive some pin, monitor other pins for change of level. With this you'll be able to find signal-to-signal and signal-to ground shorts. Also, if you test signals on LCD side with multimeter, you'll be able to find shorts to Vdd and breaks.

Also, don't you think your problem might be with some error in initialisation sequence and its timings? In my experience there are most problems with LCD. E.g. LCD need delays after some of initialisation commands, also contrroller mey need to keep relation beween some parameters (mostly row timing vs row length)